# Where are my files on a new ec2 instance?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to install appscale on a fresh AMI instance. I logged in as ec2-user and created a new folder with mkdir ec2.

Now, when i ftp into the server i cannot fine my new folder called ec2. Anyone know where to look?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ec2-user` directory is in `/home/ec2-user`
Be sure you are using the same user for SSH and FTP.

On a security point of view, I would discourage to use FTP as it is sending password in clear text.  SCP is recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I already found it last night. And yes, i used scp, not ftp. However, when i run the appscale tools build "bash appscale_build.sh" I get "n/a is not supported". Worst error message ever. Nothing more that that. Im trying to install appscale 1.11.0 so i can run an old GAE codebase on ec2. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, can't help with AppScale :-(